# Select list box display double same value

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a list box that contain name of persons. In the column "Requestor" there are many names that repeat with the same name. So when I make the list box, the name shows all the name and some name shows more than one with the same name. How can i make the name just come out one only. Below are my codes.

```
<select name="requestor" id="requestor">
    <option value="0">-- Select requestor --</option>
    <?php 
    $getallCapex_transaction = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM capex_transaction ");
    while($viewallCapex_transaction = mysql_fetch_array($getallCapex_transaction))
    {
    ?>
    <option id="<?php echo $viewallCapex_transaction ['Project_id'];?>"><?php 
    echo $viewallCapex_transaction['Requestor']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And one more question how can I show list of month and year that connect with mySql? can someone show me some codes. Thanks

Comment: I think I would store the results in a temporary array and run array unique or something.... still thinking.

Comment: Still waiting.....=|

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there are multiple rows with the same "Requestor" but different "Project_id", that's just how it's gonna turn out. You can select distinct by Requestor in your SQL, but that will leave you unaware of what record you're pointing at.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking that if we leave out duplicate requestors, then unique project ids may be lost.

Comment: It's a pretty hard thing to decide when we don't know the structure of the database. There _might_ be unique names for each Requestor. But if not, I would just list all of them using Distinct or Joins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in an array and some something like `array_unique` to create an unique array. Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $requestorArray = array();
?>

<select name="requestor" id="requestor">
    <option value="0">-- Select requestor --</option>
    <?php 
        $getallCapex_transaction = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM capex_transaction ");
        while($viewallCapex_transaction = mysql_fetch_array($getallCapex_transaction))
        {
            $requestorArray[$viewallCapex_transaction ['Project_id']] = $viewallCapex_transaction['Requestor'];
        }

        $requestorArray = array_unique($requestorArray);
        foreach($requestorArray as $projectId => $requestor)
    ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $projectId;?>"><?php 
            echo $requestor; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Btw thanks alot. But this code only show just one "Requestor" that have one "Project_id". They dont show other "Requestor" for other "Project_id".